# The set of subgroups of $F_2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

This question came up in our algebraic topology class and our Professor didn't know the answer. I also couldn't find an answer so far.

> What is the cardinality of the set of subgroups of $F_2$?

Here $F_2 = \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$ denotes the free group on two generators. The cardinality of the set of subgroups is clearly bounded below by $\aleph_0$ (as $F_2$ contains subgroups of all countable ranks) and above by $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: There are uncountably many non-isomorphic $2$-generator groups.  The kernels of surjections from $F_2$ to these groups give uncountably many distinct subgroups of $F_2$.

Comment: This not only shows that there are uncountably many subgroups, but even that there are uncountably many *normal* subgroups. Thank you.

Comment: To sharpen the statement: the cardinality is the continuum $2^{\aleph_0}$. Source: https://books.google.com/books?id=s9F71NJxwzoC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=cardinality+of+2-generator+groups&source=bl&ots=ctEu99sG56&sig=J8LKjWO2yUhtpVjIIH5d0Jszb7U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFvoTf9_DNAhUHbB4KHa_PA4IQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=cardinality%20of%202-generator%20groups&f=false

Comment: I think if you look at the space of infinite index subgroups as a subset of $2^{F_2}$ with the product topology, you will find that it is closed and contains no isolated points and hence is a Cantor set.

Comment: Actually the set of fully charateristic subgroups (= stable under endomorphisms) itself has continuum cardinal. Since such subgroups parameterize varieties of groups, they are quite important.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg indeed, but if the OP didn't know that there are uncountably many subgroups, he might also not know why it has no isolated point (this is based on the LERF property, the Marshal Hall theorem, which is well-known to specialists but far from trivial).

Comment: @YCor, if he was studying topology he might be able to imagine how to tweak a covering space outside a finite graph containing the basepoint to see that an infinite index subgroup is not isolated. I was going to write this as an answer rather than a comment by realized it is a bit much to write up for a general audience.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg thanks for the hint; viewed this way I realize that the LERF property of free groups is easier then than the full statement of M. Hall's theorem, and actually it's even easier (and enough here) to show that every finitely generated subgroup of infinite index is the intersection of a decreasing sequence of larger subgroups.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is clear that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ subgroups of the free group $F_\infty$ on countably many generators (because each subset of a free generating set generates a different subgroup). In addition, it is well known that $F_2$ contains a subgroup that is not finitely generated. Since all subgroups of a free group are free, this subgroup is isomorphic to $F_\infty$. Then every subgroup of this $F_\infty$ is also a subgroup of $F_2$, which means that $F_2$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ subgroups. (However, this simple argument does not prove Andy Putman's stronger statement that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ *normal* subgroups.)

Comment: There are explicit 2-generated groups of $3 \times 3$-matrices over $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z) [t,t^{-1}]$ whose center is isomorphic to $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty} (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$. Thus, these groups (and hence $F_2$) have $2^{\aleph_0}$ normal subgroups.